# PHP: preg_match_all() '/((\d{9})\.html)/s'

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm using this function:

```
preg_match_all('/((\d{9})\.html)/s', $content, $results);
```

It works fine but i just want the digits as results in the array $results[], not the whole "searchstring".

Any ideas? I'm sure there is a solution but I forgot how to do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a minimum you can get rid of the outer brackets: `/(\d{9})\.html/s`, but the full string is always included in `$results[0]`.

You can get just the digits from `$results[2]` (or `$results[1]` in my example).

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/((\d{9})\.html)/s', $content, $allResults);
$results = $allResults[2][0];
```